# How to find the rolling percentage Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, percentage, rolling-computation

I'd like to know the win percentage of a horse using a rolling count.
This is what I have at the moment

| Horse | Another header | Wins |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 |
| A | 2 | 1 |
| A | 1 | 2 |
| B | 3 | 0 |
| B | 1 | 1 |
| B | 3 | 1 |

This is what I want.

| Horse | Another header | Wins | Win Perc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | 100% |
| A | 2 | 1 | 50% |
| A | 1 | 2 | 66% |
| B | 3 | 0 | 0% |
| B | 1 | 1 | 50% |
| B | 3 | 1 | 33% |

If possible it would be good to knwo win percentage in total and win percentage over the past 3 races??

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"horse": ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"], "wins": [1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1]})
>>> df
  horse  wins
0     A     1
1     A     1
2     A     2
3     B     0
4     B     1
5     B     1
>>> df["win_pct"] = df["wins"] / (df.groupby("horse").cumcount() + 1) * 100
>>> df
  horse  wins     win_pct
0     A     1  100.000000
1     A     1   50.000000
2     A     2   66.666667
3     B     0    0.000000
4     B     1   50.000000
5     B     1   33.333333
```

Comment: Thanks, how would I get a win pct for the previous 2 races?